# How to create list and initialize only some of it's values in Python (in comparison to C++)

Tags: python, c++, list, pointers

I need to create an `List of size N` and then initialize only `N-1th` and `N-2th` elements only. Which means **if the size of the list is 5** then it should only contain **elements in 3rd and 4th position**.

i know how to do it in `C++` but is there any way to implement it in `Python`?

> for example:  In C++

```
int *n = new int[5];
n[3] = 20
n[4] = 10

//and if we print the output it will show some garbage values in index 0, 1, 2 and will print 20 10 which is the values we initailized
```

**How can i do it in python? or anything similar to this!**

Comment: Python doesn't have uninitialized variables. What value do you want to be in the other elements? You have to choose one.

Comment: oh! i have heard about using arrays from numpy . can i do similar things using that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, list must be initialized with values.

Closest thing you can do:

```
N   = 5
lst = [0] * (N-2) + [20, 10]
```

This:

1. Fills the `N-2` elements of a list with default value `0`
2. Sets the value for the last two elements
3. Concatenates the zeros and last two elements sub-lists of stages 1 & 2

Comment: Thanks..  the output for this will look like.. [0, 0, 0, 20, 10].

Answer (score 0):

In python,

```
array=[]
length=5
for i in range(length):
  array.append(0)
array[3]=20
array[4]=10
```

Edit: As pointed out by kabanus, a more efficient way to do this would be-

```
array=[0]*length
```

Instead of the `for` loop.

Comment: This is not a recommended way of doing something like this in Python. Usually `[value]*N` is a common much more optimal idiom for such a thing.